# ckeditor auto add a span tag in li

Tags: html, tags, ckeditor

how can i configure the Ckeditor to add automatic a `<span>` tag in a new `<li></li>` element.

Like so `<li><span></span></li>`

Thanks for helping

Comment: And empty span? Why would you possibly want that? This sounds like an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Or would you want the span tag to actually have a class or a style, in which case there might be a point.

Comment: Normal when add a new ul list with the Ckeditor then he create sympliy a normal <ul><li></li></ul>.....  but i wont <ul><li><span></span></li></ul>

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Comment: It's ok, no need to apologise :). I just want to know why do you want to do that? What is the reason? Because I think that maybe what you are trying to do can be done without the spans easier

Comment: a ok  . I want do that to style it over a extern .css file on my website.  ul{color:gray};  li.span{color:black}.....  so i had gray bulitpoints whitout a gfx-grafic.  My site you cant see wat i mean: [link](http://www.dildosbilliger.de/dildo-xskin-8-grade-nature.html)

Comment: If possible, I'd say using the :before method would be easier here. http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/q9RRg/ If not, can you post-process your data? How do you save the data? Adding the span there should be really easy to do.

Comment: i do it with your css3 tip.  you are right it its easyer to do it so-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative route to style the UL bullet points differently from the text within them, there is a CSS hack using `:before` you can use - it's not pretty though! See fiddle by BoltClock here: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/q9RRg/

The relevant CSS code is this:

```
ul li {
    color: black;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

ul li:before {
    content: '\2022 ';
    color: red;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

If this is not usable, the secondary option would be to post-process your data. During your saving phase, simply add the spans to any LI element where the first child is not yet a span. I do recommend adding a class to the spans for future usage and easy targeting as well.

Comment: This answer rewritten and migrated from the comments